# MySQL Whitespace Issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, ms-access

I'm working with a client to convert his Access database into a MySQL one. He also has a website linked to the database...here is where the problem lies:

The fields in the database have too many whitespaces. EX: Instead of having space like this:

```
4.0L Engine
```

the spacing is like this:

```
4.0L   Engine
```

This causes browsers like `IE` and `Firefox` to throw an error because it looks like they are displaying the incorrect amount of whitespace.

I know one solution is to go in and manually fix the whitespacing but it has 1000's of records and it will waste too much time.

I'm using CodeIgniter for his website to select the values from the database. Is there anyway I can make CodeIgniter, IE, and Firefox display the correct number of whtiespaces or automate the process of correcting the whitespaces without manually doing them?

Edit: Here is an example of an actual string in the database:

```
3.2L 196 OHV ENG - 1956-65  (CAST IRON ENG)
```

and here is how it's shown in firefox/IE

```
3.2L 196 OHV ENG - 1956-65 (CAST IRON ENG)
```

Comment: Unless you have white-space:pre set in your css, the browser will only show one space.

Comment: Can you clarify what the difference between the two strings is? Also, is trim($string) not an option?

Comment: I added that to my css in the body element but it still doesn't work. I'm still getting errors saying that no results were found in the database.

Comment: Sure edited the post to show the differenence in the database and IE/Firefox. Wouldn't trim get rid of all whitespaces?

Comment: IE and Firefox are browsers, not databases. What do your table and your query look like?

Comment: I know they are....the info from the database isn't displayed right into those two browsers. My query is "SELECT * FROM enginecore WHERE Cat1 = "GM" AND Cylinders = "V6" AND Cat3 = "3.2L 196 OHV ENG - 1956-65 (CAST IRON ENG)". The query is built based on what the user choses. This works fine in Chrome but IE/Firefox give me problems

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of an error being thrown because of white space, but you could always create a script that

- pulls down the record from the database
- manipulates the data through [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) -- looking for extra white space and replacing it with the correct white space
- then updates the record in the database

If you loop through all of the records, this would only need to be done once. Then the data in the database is as you intend.

Comment: So the two different strings I have that I just added to my original post shouldn't be causing this problem? My query involves 3 WHERE clauses and all the fields in the table are varchars